# Registering resources in Dropwizard

Tags: dropwizard

I am unable to register multiple resources in the `run()` method of my Dropwizard application. When I do,I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" MultiException[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A metric named io.dropwizard.db.ManagedPooledDataSource.postgresql.active already exists, java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.NonBlockingThread@27f74733]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:329)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand.run(ServerCommand.java:43)
at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:76)
at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:70)
at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:73)
at com.xxx.xxx.yyy.GobblerHTTPApplication.main(GobblerHTTPApplication.java:19)
```

Comment: can you add your code ?

Comment: Also details such as the version of dropwizard you're using may be useful.

Answer (score 6):

if you happend to init the databases using Hibernate, eg. by using the following piece of code in you main application (twice):

```
private final HibernateBundle<Cfg> hib1 = new HibernateBundle<Cfg>(ImmutableList.of(SomeHibernateModel.class), new SessionFactoryFactory()) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(Cfg configuration) {
        return configuration.getDatabaseFactory();
    }
};
```

then it is helpful to overwrite another method: the ´name()´ method. That method is the soure for providing the last part of your metric name (the ´.postgresql.active ´ part) E.g. like this:

```
private final HibernateBundle<Cfg> hib1 = new HibernateBundle<Cfg>(ImmutableList.of(SomeHibernateModel.class), new SessionFactoryFactory()) {
    @Override
    public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory(Cfg configuration) {
        return configuration.getDatabaseFactory();
    }
    @Override
    protected String name() {
        return "hibernate.accesslog";
    }

};
```

Comment: This approach worked perfectly for me, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @stve Beware that  --- if you intend to use `@UnitOfWork` -- you will only have a session for one of both. This issue has been raised in https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/issues/1217 and been merged just a few days ago. So it might be not yet been fixed in your version

Comment: thanks for pointing me to that issue. I am having issues with `@UnitOfWork` as you indicated. Fortunately, it looks like 0.9.0 is going to be released shortly.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are initializing instances of Postgres twice for each resource which is not required. You can simply first initialize all your stores, etc. and then register your resources. Do it something like as follows:-

```
    /* Service manager */
    environment.lifecycle().manage(new XYZServiceManager());

    /* Adding Resources */
    environment.jersey().register(new FirstResource());
    environment.jersey().register(new SecondResource());
```

Hope this will solve your problem.